MPFB2 Rig Helpers Transform Differently for Left and Right Side of Armature
I try to translate an animated armature and found in Graph Editor that right side rig helpers translate correctly but left side's do inversely.
What I do is, everything with default properties:

In Blender (4.1) add a MPFB2 (v2.0-a4) human "from scratch".
Add a standard rig "Default (no toes)".
Then add rig helpers.
In Pose Mode select bones "root", and the rig helpers for knees and feet.
Insert keyframe for location at frame 1. Then go to frame 2 and move the selected bones a bit forward in walking direction and insert keyframe.

Now if I look into Graph Editor I see that
right foot and knee: move in negative direction (that's correct), but
left foot and knee: move in positive direction.
When trying to translate the whole animation in Graph Editor by selecting all location graphs and moving up and down, of course, the animation is not translated, but the feets and knees move in opposite directions (forward and backward, not both forward or both backward).
What's wrong? Is it a problem with the armature, or do I expect this to work in another way than it's intended?

"MPFB2" appears to be an external application and nothing to do with Blender so you'll have to ask the addon author(s) Also what do you mean by 'standard rig "Default (no toes)"' and adding 'rig helpers'? Images and sharing your Blend file may help us see what you mean!

Thanks. MPFB2 is MakeHuman's Blender plugin. Meanwhile I found the problem. The IK bones in blender had "Inherit Rotation" and "Local Location" set.
